# Get result if end_date is 1 month before current month

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In the `sales` table I have a field called `end_date` (date type),

I want to display the result if the `end_date` is current month.

also If the `end_date` is future date then dispay the result if `end_date` is 1 month before current month.

How to get that to work in SQL query?

Comment: How can a date be in the future *and* 1 month before the current month?  I thought you meant "today's month" when you wrote "current month", but I think you must mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example like that:

```
select *
from sales
where DATE_FORMAT(date_end, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(now() - interval 1 month, '%Y%m')
```

Comment: Will it also work if end_date is current month as well? I have `2011-12-17` end_date - not getting any result.

Comment: Also if end_date like 4 months ago, it should display as well.

Answer (score 0):

Returns all rows where `end_date` is current month or any day earlier (after your comment: "Also if end_date like 4 months ago, it should display as well." – user791022):

```sql
select * from sales where end_date < adddate(last_day(now()), 1)
```

ps. I don't have a MySQL right now so I can't test it.

Comment: You have got this right but if end_date is next month then display it depending on the date.

Comment: Review and clarify your question then probably you'll get a correct answer. Expected result for sample data would be fine.